# Error when solving a symbolic equation in a nested for loop

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve a symbolic equation for b in a nested as shown below but i am getting the following error:

```
Error in solve (line 226)
[eqns,vars,options] = getEqns(varargin{:});

 Error in Problem_1 (line 20)
    s1=solve(tand(t(j))==2*cotd(b).*((M1(i).^2*sind(b).^2-1)./(M1(i).^2*(G+cosd(2*b))+2)),b); %solve for beta
```

code:

```
syms b x
M1 = [1.6,1.8,2.0,2.2,2.6,3.2,4.0];
t = [0,8,16,24,32,40];
%M1 = 6; %Mach number M1
%t = 6;   %Deflection angle theta
G = 1.4;  %gamma
M = numel(M1); %Number of Mach 1 elements
T = numel(t); %Number of theta elements
Mach2 = zeros(M,T); %Matrix for M2
P_rat = zeros(M,T); %Matrix for Pressure ratio
for i=1:M
    for j=1:T
        s1=solve(tand(t(j))==2*cotd(b).*((M1(i).^2*sind(b).^2-1)./(M1(i).^2*(G+cosd(2*b))+2)),b); %solve for beta
    b = double(s1)+180; %beta
    end

end
```

Comment: If you just convert the result to double why are you even solving symbolically? You also overwrite `b` so it's no longer a symbolic variable (on the line after `s1=...`). The full error message explicitly tells you this: "Second argument must be a vector of symbolic variables."

Comment: @David matlab defaults the answer to symbolic and I need a numeric value to use it for my calculations... Unless there's a numeric method to solve for b that I don't know about

Comment: Matlab has many numerical root-finding methods. Try `fzero` to start.